# Is there a way in ActionScript to force an IMMEDIATE update of the stage, _not_ after an event?

Tags: actionscript-3

I know the method MouseEvent.updateAfterEvent() or KeyboardEvent.updateAfterEvent() which will force a re-render of the stage just after the event is handled rather than waiting for the next frame.

However, I need a method to force an immediate render at the very moment I call it. Is there such a method?

Actually my problem comes from the demential design of ActionScript's printing API (PrintJob). Inconsistent with the whole ActionScript architecture, when you call PrintJob.start(), everything is completely frozen while the printing dialog is shown until the user clicks the print or cancel button. Execution of any code after the PrintJob.start() call is resumed after  that.

Among a lot of other much worse issues coming from this gigantic design flaw, there is mine:

```
public function someMouseOrKeyboardEventHandler() {
  somethingThatUpdatesTheDisplayList();
  var somePrintJob=new PrintJob();
  somePrintJob.start();
  //...
  somePrintJob.send();
}
```

When this handler of mine is called, the changes made to the display list will not be visible until after the printing dialog has been closed, so I can't, for example, show something on the screen just before I open the print dialog.

updateAfterEvent() won't help a bit (already tried it). It won't change a thing, since it only forces rendering after the event handler code is executed.

Is there any updateRightNow()-like thing?

Comment: have you tried validateNow()  I think that will do the trick for you.

Comment: @JasonReeves what class's validateNow()? If you're talking about what I think you're talking about, that seems something totally flex-specific and completely unrelated to forcing a render of the stage; seems to be more like telling some flex framework object to recalculate sizes for a redraw that anyway will happen at the next enterFrame at best. I'm talking about pure generic ActionScript, and low-level redrawing.

Comment: UIComponent.  Yes I do use it in flex, but I thought it was purely as3 thing and according to the [class reference for UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html) it is since flash player 10.2. My apologies if I misunderstood its availability in raw as3.

Comment: @Jason: Cool, I didn't know about that class. I don't think that the actual rendering is forced during the call, though -- but worth a try?

Comment: well I can say this...in flex... it is immediate.  I used it last week for when new renderers get added to a chat message list... I animate the list (smooth scroll it to the new message).  problem was when the collection changed... the renderer didn't exist yet... so I call validateNow() then my list dataGroup has a new height with the new item renderer rendered inside it. and my scroll effect works great.  so it does work inline in-function in flex.

Comment: @JasonReeves IF in flex it's truly immediate (meaning it refreshes the true render at the very moment you call it), then it would mean that there is a non-flex generic lower-level method that flex calls to do that, and that I could call too. Because Flex is written IN ActionScript, and can't do anything that ActionScript itself can't do. I'm afraid your test case is one where you could never tell the difference whether the re-rendering is immediate or deferred till the end of the event handling.

Comment: uhh.. yeah... that was my point. If I can use it why can't you?? and it is immediate.  you can do stuff like function proveIt(){trace(height) validateNow() trace(height)}.. and height will be different in each trace(if changes were pending).

Comment: @JasonReeves that doesn't mean that it's actually redrawn. It only proves that it is recomputed.

Comment: ok then don't try it... I'm only making suggestions on what has worked for me when the displayLit wasn't accurate.  If it won't work in your scenario.. it won't.  If you don't want to try don't.  That's why I made this as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you unfortunately can't force an update in the middle of your code.

You can, however, wait until the next frame to call `start()` on the PrintJob; this will give Flash time to update the stage before everything freezes.

Comment: Yeah I can already think of a handfull of workarounds (for this particular situation), but I was hoping there would be a real solution. Actually I guess one would never need such a thing (force an update in the middle of the code; so it makes sense it doesn't exist) if it weren't because of such gigantic design flaws in the API as an all-blocking, only-synchronous, core-freezing method like PrintJob.start(). You can't even have an animation or a sound keep playing while the dialog is open. It's embarassing.

Comment: @matteo: Yep. I used to like Flash, but I've given up on it; every little thing ends up plagued by issues that are annoying or sometimes even impossible to work around.